# Can AMD A-Series APU support OpenCL?

Tags: ati, fglrx, 14.10, gpu, opencl

Have spent a lot of time on this one one but can't find an answer here.

Ubuntu 14.10 clean install.
AMD A10-7700K APU with Radeon(TM) R7 Graphics x4.

1) Started with the xserver open-source wrapper and all seemed ok.

2) Installed BOINC but 'No useable GPUs found' in Event Log.

3) Reinstalled BOINC with boinc-amd-opencl but same result, except that it installed AMD graphics fglrx-updates.

4) Downloaded & installed latest Calalyst from AMD and that didn't work at all, wouldn't boot past the mauve screen!

5) Reverted back to setup above. But still no OpenCL for BOINC.

6) In case this was only a 'BOINC' glitch, I went to their website. Found some old stuff about KAVERI support, which didn't solve it.

7) Another program with this problem, darktable, also can't find OpenCL.

A snag is that there doesn't seem to a utility in Ubuntu that tells me clearly whether OpenCL is functional or not.

So conclusion? Ubuntu 14.10 + fglrx 14.201 + AMD A10-7700K = no OpenCL.

True? Hopefully someone out there knows the answer.

Comment: Does `clinfo` work?

Comment: Ken Sharp: Yes, the one in /usr/bin gives positive return for OpenCL. (Hadn't known I had clinfo!) So I suppose my original question is answered, thanks. 
Also, I've managed to get OpenCL with boinc...
Changed to fglrx-updates from Additional Drivers. Reboot to load, reinstalled boinc, then must always use boot-up manager to stop/start boinc, and OpenCL gpu processing is ok.
This didn't work when I posted my original question, but it does now!?
Hope this experience helps others.

Comment: Does the following? http://askubuntu.com/questions/563870/amd-a4-5300-and-gpu-computing-on-boinc

Comment: Did the above work?

Comment: Ken Sharp: Thanks for continuing to show an interest in this topic.

Comment: Ken Sharp: Thanks for continuing to show an interest in this topic.
Things have moved on since last year, as I'm now using Ubuntu 15.04 amd64. Boinc version is 7.4.23 including boinc-amd-opencl. I originally tried fglrx-updates but even so boinc didn't find usable gpu, even using the bum trick mentioned above. So I've kind of given up on it, since all works well with the open-source wrapper, except, of course, boinc OpenCL! But boinc does work ok anyway, although without the amd gpu horsepower.
But if anyone knows the story with ati/amd, Canonical and Open CL, I'm sure we'd all be grateful!

Comment: Ken Sharp: Tried your idea about changing ownership, but then boinc didn't work at all! So have reverted. And my error: have been using fglrx-updates all along. More than ever convinced that OpenCL not available in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Did you remember to `chown -R /var/lib/boinc-client/*` (or similar)?

Comment: No, I used Properties - Permissions which I assume does the same thing. You need some Nautilus plug-ins installed to do this easily. 15.04 has a slightly different file arrangements, but I think I got it right. Also, to my surprise, I've just found that darktable finds and used OpenCL! More & more coming down to boinc, I think. Would be lovely to use GPU with this, but does work without it.

Comment: Did you run Nautilus as root? Only root (or sudo, or user:boinc) can change owner/permissions on those directories. It may have failed silently otherwise.

Comment: You can just use right-click if you install nautilus-admin extension. Same thing. 
Now satisfied that OpenCL does work in Ubuntu 15.04, eg recent update to darktable. So maybe it all lies with boinc after all.

Comment: And it asks you to log in as sudo/root? I'm still on an old version of Ubuntu. It's a permissions problem in Ubuntu, not really BOINC's fault. For reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/boinc/+bug/1407452

Comment: Back to this one! Yes, nautilus-admin does ask for password. Guessed you're using older version, 15.04 is slightly different. We have
/etc/default/boinc-client & /etc/init.d/boinc-default. Your Step 2:
12 # The BOINC core client will be started with the permissions of this user.
13 BOINC_USER="boinc" Further down: 24 # Here you can specify additional options to pass to the BOINC core client. 25 # Type 'boinc --help' or 'man boinc' for a full summary of allowed options. 26 #BOINC_OPTS="--allow_remote_gui_rpc" 27 BOINC_OPTS=""
Opt is --start_delay X (Xsecs), maybe same as 'sleep10'. ..contd.

Comment: Contd.. Step3: We have 28 BOINC_USER=boinc and  
101 start() 
107 if [ -n "$DISPLAY" -a -x /usr/bin/xhost ]; then
       # grant the boinc client to perform GPU computing
       xhost local:boinc || echo -n "xhost error ignored, GPU computing may not be possible"
    110 fi 
Some significance here? In this case,  your Step 5&6 exactly the same? Your opinion very welcome, since not a programmer am nervous to make changes unless sure!

Comment: Contd.. Afterthought; both above files owned by 'root'. Also have folder /etc/boinc-client owned by root, containing cc_config.xml owned by 'BOINC core client', global_prefs_override.xml, gui_rpc_auth.cfg, remote_host.cfg all owned by 'root'. If significant.

Comment: Everything in `/etc/boinc-client` and `/var/lib/boinc-client` should really be owned by user running boinc, which is probably `user:boinc`, although in my example it's the logged-in user `user:user1`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu dropped support for the old fglrx drivers in 14.04.04 recent patches (they USED to work but Ubuntu changed something that BROKE the support, so you pretty much have to stick with 14.04.03 or earlier).

AMD has NEVER offered any "official" support for OpenCL on the A10 series in their ROCm or AMDGPU-PRO series drivers that DO work with more recent Ubuntu versions, and it appears they plan to NEVER DO SO even though they DO support discrete GPUs that are OLDER than many of the A10 series APUs.

The ROCm stack will SOMETIMES work with the GCN-based A10 APUs (A10-6xxx I think, and definitely the A10-7xxx and later), but that's very hit-or-miss on if it will work or not on a given installation - and is NOT officially supported, so forget getting any SUPPORT out of AMD on such a setup.

Also, if you are going to use fglrx at all, it would be better to use the final release version 14.302 instead of the older .201 version
Corresponds to AMD driver version 15.12 (.201 I believe was 15.07 or so).