# Not able to use Radeon HD6950 for computations on GPU (OpenCl)

Tags: 14.04, ati, opencl

Am not able to use Radeon HD6950 for computations on GPU (OpenCl) in Ubuntu (works fine in Windows with a Dell driver with dual boot).

Output of

lspci | grep VGA

is

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]

When clinfo is run it shows (among other things)

```
Device Type: CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
```

which seems odd.  These are 3 options for drivers at System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers, they are

1) Using X.Org X server...

2) Using Video driver for the AMD  ...

3) Using Video driver for the AMD ... updates ...

none of them let me use the gpu for computations.
When the newest driver from AMD fglrx_14.501-OUbuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb is launched, the Ubuntu Software Center gives the error

Dependency is not satisfiable: fglrx-core

Using Ubuntu 14.04, but am new to OS so might be my mistake.

Have been testing with examples in bin folder of clBLAS at https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS/releases, which give error clGetDeviceIDs() failed with -1
meaning it didn't find the GPU.

Thanks

Comment: Please try the instructions here and let us know if it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/563870/amd-a4-5300-and-gpu-computing-on-boinc

Comment: Did the above work?

Comment: I gave up and bought a Nvidia card - it works fine with Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

DO NOT use Software Centre for installing drivers EVER! I tried it and it messed up my computer a number of times until I ultimately quit using it accept for small programs. First make sure in the drivers tab as you said, you are using the X.org driver. Download the latest driver from amd.com and launch the installer. Launch it through terminal if you plan to install it directly on the distribution rather than on X.org. It will take about 4 minutes to install, and you know it finished when the terminal command is done. Then reboot your computer. After reboot, go on this link to download OpenCL from the AMD website, and install it using the terminal. Then you should be good.
http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/